# When to break a broken While loop?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have a while loop that waits for a local setting value to no longer be null. In the event that something is borked and the value remains null, is there some sort of best practice for how you should break out of the loop? Right now I just have it counting up to 100 and if it's looped 100 times to break the loop:

```
int i = 0;

while (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MediaInfoSaved"] == null)
{
await Task.Delay(15);
       i++;

       if(i >= 100)
       {
              break;
       }
}
```

The loop is waiting for a process in a full trust helper to finish and return it's result. The process can take a while to complete sometimes (0.1-1 second).

Comment: there's no general rule as to when you should break the loop, what you should ask yourself is, how long you want to wait for this check, and if it fails the check what you need this thing to do asap.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! That's a useful way to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value (represented as 100 in your code) in a config file so it's easily changed if needed. If issues pop up later you can adjust it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is expected to take up to a second, then wait for just a second. No need to loop and increment a counter:

```
private async Task<object> GetLocalSettingAsync()
{
    const string SettingName = "MediaInfoSaved";

    // Try to get the value immediately:
    var setting = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[SettingName];
    if (setting != null)
        return setting;

    // Wait for one second only.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    // Return either a value or null.
    return ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[SettingName];
}
```

If you want to exit as fast as possible but wait for *up to* a second, then spin in a loop and poll the property:

```
private async Task<object> GetLocalSettingAsync()
{
    const string SettingName = "MediaInfoSaved";
    DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

    object setting;
    do
    {
        setting = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[SettingName];
        if (setting != null)
            break;
        //optionally wait here:
        await Task.Delay(15);
    } while (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds < 1);

    return setting;
}
```

I am afraid it doesn't get any better unless the object that you are monitoring raises some kind of event or callback when there is data available.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

The process could take significantly less than a second (around 0.1 seconds). Since the user is waiting while this process completes, I'd like for to take the least amount of time possible. That's why I have it check every so often to see if the value is no longer null.

Comment: @HooptyDoopty: Then you can spin in a loop. See my edit for an (untested) example.

Answer (score -2):

It is very common practice to implement a timeout, where you wait a specified amount of time (if you have an idea how long the process *should* be taking) before breaking out of the loop. This is basically what you have implemented. If you think it shouldn't take more than 1 second to complete, make sure it breaks the loop after 1.5-2 seconds. There may be more effective ways to implement this, like using the actual time within the system.